# The process.env.variable works in local development but after deploying to Heroku it stops working. I use nuxt.js

Tags: heroku, nuxt.js, .env

process.env.variable is working in local development but after deploying to Heroku its not working again. I use nuxt.js

The value shows as undefined:
https://prnt.sc/l1GMK6xAQP-V

The config var is correct. I restarted the app. still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

.env file:

```ini
BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000
ORIGIN_HEADER=localhost
```

nuxt.config.js

```js
export default {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL,
    originHeader: process.env.ORIGIN_HEADER
  }
}
```

.vue component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Base URL: {{ baseUrl }}</p>
    <p>Origin Header: {{ originHeader }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
    
<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    baseUrl() {
      return this.$config.baseUrl
    },
    originHeader() {
        return this.$config.originHeader
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

`publicRuntimeConfig` is intended to be used for configuration values that are safe to be publicly exposed, such as API endpoints or public-facing URLs.

`privateRuntimeConfig`, on the other hand, is intended for configuration values that should be kept private and should not be publicly exposed, such as API keys or secrets.